# ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit: What is the maximum number of items in ComboBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, combobox

Im building a small form using ComboBoxes with lots of items, and it seems after exactly 510 items added, the ComboBox stops working, and the combo button is hidden.

Is there any maximum number of items that can be added? Or this might be other problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a more general problem here.  A combobox with 500 items is completely useless.

Comment: Why? I remeber you that the ComboBox is also a TextBox with auto-search. Check the official sample: http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx. I dont see why a combo with 500 items is "completely useless".

Comment: Tom is right. The implementation shown in the link has a scrollbar and it will auto-search as you type. This could be very convenient if one was considering using a text field and a listbox ... this combobox puts both all in one for ya.

Comment: However, 510 items is a lot for one single list. You should consider breaking down the structure finding some kind of pattern. Let the user narrow down the results using smaller lists ... one at a time. This will increase speed and make sure you are not overloading one combobox or listbox.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by stops working?

Comment: Sure, what happens is that the arrow button that displays the items simply disapears, and the autosearch doesnt display nothing, even if i type. I checked the html code and the button has the style "display:hidden". Perhaps is some problem with the CSS, however the ComboBox works perfectly with less than 500 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried an AJAX ComboBox with 10000 items and it worked fine, although it took a long time to load (about 10 seconds). So there is not a limit at 510 items. Your problem must be something else.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the test, i guess the problem is mine then, probably CSS. I just cant figure out where, but i will make some more tests.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, with that many items in a combobox you should redesign your screen. Once you get over a certain number of items, it is faster for the user to write something into a text box.

Having said that 510 is not a round number so the problem is probably not with the combobox. I would guess that at that point the payload for however you are getting the items becomes larger than the configuration allows, the combo does not get all the information it was expecting and therefore hangs waiting for the info.

Comment: But the combo box is also a text box, with sugestion and everything... I have seen it in plenty of sites to select countries for example. I think you are misunderstating the funcionality of the combo box. Check this http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx.

Back on the question, i get the items from the database with a SP. To be more specific, the items are all the cities from my region.

Comment: @Tom, how do you get the data from the SP to the browser, I guess you must have a JSON service, how is it implemented?

Comment: I attach the items to the ComboBox in the code-bedind, something like this: "cbCities.DataSource = GetCitiesFromDB();" (this method calls the SP and returns a DataTable).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use a combination of controls to filter your items into smaller groups. For example, if you have 500 cars, you could filter by manufacturer (in a combobox) and make (in another combobox).

Comment: Im already filtering by regions, however there is regions with lots of cities, the maximum is 600 i think.

Comment: Maybe filter by state (Which people may be more familiar with than some ideas of a "region")?

Comment: Depends on the country where you live. State doesnt mean much here :)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to break the list down into categories and use more than one ComboBox? If you added a dropdown to choose the category (geographic region, product group, or some other filter), then the user could choose a category. That would be applied to filter the list displayed in the original, second ComboBox. That would make a much better UI, and you'd be passing a lot less data to the browser.

I'm thinking of the Cascading DropDown demonstrated [here.](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)

Comment: Im already doing it with comboboxes =) However with a specific set of values i got nearly 600 items on the last combo.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm talking about. Also, just because you are already doing it one way doesn't mean you shouldn't consider doing it another way. Do it the right way now and save yourself a lot of pain later :)

Comment: Hehe well said... However i get this logistic information from my national Postal Service, and i cant see how i can partitionate more the information, that is already partitioned (there was around 24000 tows). Maybe doing a map or something, but for what im payed for, its just not worth it :P

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might have to do with Internet Explorer. We had a similar problem couple months ago, where we wouldn't have any problem with it in Firefox or Chrome, but when we were to show the combobox on IE, the screen would freeze and it would start responding again in a couple minutes.

Whether you need a combobox that big is another issue which doesn't have to do with your question, so I'll try to answer :)

Please take a look at this article
http://kemcik.blogspot.com/2009/11/very-slow-updatepanel-refresh-when.html

Answer (score 0):

Hat tip to beeno's answer [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1099354.aspx?Cascading%20Dropdownlist%20Item%20Count%20Limit) which worked for me:

This limitation is most likely being made by the default setting of maxJsonLength in your web.config.  You can specify the size like this in web.config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1234567"></jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Bear in mind that the size is characters, not record count.  The default setting is 102400